# Select specific from database with a formular

Tags: php, forms, select, mysqli, where-clause

Hey iam making a website where you can buy pigs, and when the customers want to buy a pig they can select beetween diffrent things they want in the pig.
All the questions is yes or no questions, so far. Example:

Would you like the pig to be fat?
Yes x
No

And then i have a database where the pigs are and it says yes or no if it is fat for example. 
But to the point, if the customer select it wants a fat big with big ears i want the result only to show pigs who are fat and have big ears.

This is some of my select code:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="resultat.php">
  <label>Mellem 7 mrd. og 3 år</label><br />
  <input type="radio" name="valg" value="ja" required="required" />ja<br />
  <input type="radio" name="valg" value="nej" required="required" />nej<br />
  <label>Antal smågrise over 10 pr. fødsel</label><br />
  <input type="radio" name="valg2" value="ja" required="required" />ja<br />
  <input type="radio" name="valg2" value="nej" required="required" />nej<br />
  <label>Hurtig vægtforøgelse (over 600 gram pr. dag over 180 dage)</label><br />
  <input type="radio" name="valg3" value="ja" required="required" />ja<br />
  <input type="radio" name="valg3" value="nej" required="required" />nej<br />
  <label>Fedt</label><br />
  <input type="radio" name="valg4" value="ja" required="required" />ja<br />
  <input type="radio" name="valg4" value="nej" required="required" />nej<br />
  <label>Kraftige ben</label><br />
  <input type="radio" name="valg5" value="ja" required="required" />ja<br />
  <input type="radio" name="valg5" value="nej" required="required" />nej<br />
</form>
```

This is some of the resultat.php code:

```
<?php 
  require_once 'dbconn.php'; //forbind til databasen
  // Forklar, hvilke data du vil have
  $sql = "SELECT navn, ung, antal, vaegt, fedt, ben, levende, overlevelse, overlevelsefirst, bornweight FROM grise";
  // Send forespørgslen til databasen og modtag svaret
  $result = $conn->query($sql);
?>
```

Comment: build up a "where" clause. any radio button which is "ja" gets added to the where.

Comment: it is not that easy with prepared statements